# Erro na instalação do Xamarin - JDK não instala

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

Olá! [Estou com esse problema após a conclusão da instalação do Xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b55f4.jpg).

Já tentei baixar o sdk pelo site da Oracle, mas o instalador simplesmente não inicia, nada acontece.

Também já tentei desinstalar o VS2017 completamente e reinstalar, mas o mesmo erro acontece.

Já tentei baixar o sdk separado num .zip pelo site do androidstudio e referenciar no VS, mas ele não reconhece. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Log error: https://pastebin.com/hT7h94tp

Comment: Quando você diz referenciar, você quis dizer dentro do Visual Studio, nas configurações do Xamarin? Ou em outro local?

Comment: Dentro do Visual Studio, onde ele pede o caminho do SDK

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema!

Answer (score 0):

Baixei o Android Studio, pelas configurações no Android Studio achei a referência do caminho do SDK (que dessa vez baixou e instalou com sucesso) e colei na referência no Visual Studio.